# Android: Updating the sent box afer sending an sms

Tags: android

My app sends an sms and I would like to update the phone sent box 
as if the sms was sent bu the user.
How can this be done ?

Comment: heyy......for my Xiaomi phone i am not able to add sent msg in sent box. using same code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this lines after `smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null,desc, sentPI, deliveredPI);`:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put("address", number);
values.put("body", desc); 

getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

Comment: i would be glad if that would help you! :)