# catch & save outging sms to my app & the native app

Tags: android

iv`e created an SMS app with a db that saves almost all of the messages.

the problem starts when i want to save (1) my app outgoing messages to the native SMS app - the mmssms.db & the (2) outging native SMS messages to my app db.

i searched all over and failed to find a proper example for that question,especially for the second one.

iv`e found that its all about the ContentResolver like this:

[Detecting SMS incoming and outgoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735571/detecting-sms-incoming-and-outgoing)

but i cant figure how.

please help me :)

tanks!

EDIT:

the aswer for the (1) question is :
[Android: Updating the sent box afer sending an sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763575/android-updating-the-sent-box-afer-sending-an-sms)

still searching for the (2) answer.